# Why Padmavathi not stayed with Lord Venkateshwara swamy on Seven Hills in Tirumala instead stayed at Tiruchanoor?

Tags: lakshmi, venkateshwara, tirupati

Why Goddess Padmavathi not stayed with Lord Venkateshwara swamy on Seven Hills in Tirumala instead stayed/settled at Tiruchanoor?

When Goddess Sri Lakshmi met Padmavathi?

At which instance or what situation Lord Venkateshwara swamy has became Idol on Seven Hills Tirumala?